# MIME type of file pointed to by url

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Javascript: Is there a way to find the mime type of the file that a URL points to?

I'm writing a chrome extension to replace links to mp4 files with embedded video, but my method of detecting links to videos (running href through a regex) doesn't work for URLs that redirect to valid files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can contact the server to find out the mime type. Use the `HEAD` HTTP method to prevent the server from sending the actual content. You can use `XMLHttpRequest` to make the `HEAD` request from JavaScript.